# AspNet OpenAuth missing LinqToTwitter OAuthToken?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth, linq-to-twitter

I am using the VS2012 Web Forms template to build a site that accesses Twitter. All Log-ins are done with OAuth and target Twitter only but I want to keep the Templated External login framework and in particular the "RegisterExternalLogin" page because it handles the local membership issues for me.

In the RegisterExternalLogin page, this code

```
 var authResult = OpenAuth.VerifyAuthentication(redirectUrl);
```

happily provides the user AccessToken in authResult.ExtraData['accesstoken"] which is all I thought I would need but turns out that LinqToTwitter requires 2 tokens like this:

```
 SessionStateCredentials cred = new SessionStateCredentials
                    {
                        ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"],
                        ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"],
                        AccessToken = MyUsersAccessToken,
                        OAuthToken = [AnOAuthToken] //we no have?
                    };
```

where [AnOAuthToken] is a piece of data that does not seem to exist in .Net's OpenAuth returned authResult object.

Using the above credentials Linq2Twitter returns a "401 unauthorized" when attempting user-based actions like List subscription and I am pretty sure that it has to do with the missing OAuthToken value.

Pretty sure I have a concept wrong or am missing something silly.... any guidance appreciated!